# Ancestor event not called

Tags: extjs, extjs4

'I have a base classe, where is declared two listeners:

```
Ext.define('App.controls.CoWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
listeners: {
    show: {
        fn: function(win, opt){
            alert('opened from base class');
        },
        scope: this
    },
    close: {
        fn: function() {
            alert('closed from base class');
        }
    }
}
})
```

If I declare a new class extending this, and configure the listener, the ancestor events are not called:

```
var procura = Ext.create('App.controls.CoWindowEx', {
            listeners: {
                close: {
                    fn:function() {
                        alert('closed from extending class');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I get only "closed from extending class", when I need the two messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're overwriting the listeners config on the superclass prototype. If you must do it that way:

```
Ext.define('App.controls.CoWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    initComponent: function(){
        this.callParent();
        this.on('show', function(){
            console.log('super show');
        });
        this.on('close', function(){
            console.log('super close');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me when to use "listeners" and when not?

Comment: They achieve the same thing, the problem is that you're just overwriting the value. Os if you intend to pass listeners when you create an instance, don't put listeners on the class definition.